# Java Containers

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working on some code and was trying to add a border to a JPanel. I finally figured it out after someone told me, but I am not sure why my first line did not work. Can someone give me some insight? Here is the snip-it of code:

```
private Container currCntr;
currCntr = new JPanel();
currCntr.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));  //Doesn't work (cannot find symbol)
((JPanel)currCntr).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK)); //Works
```

Comment: you had to cast it to JPanel, because Container has no setBorder method

Comment: do `private JPanel currCntr;`

Answer (score 4):

In the second line the `JPanel` is [implicitly upcasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544233/difference-between-implicit-conversion-and-explicit-conversion) to a `Container` (an abstract super class of `JPanel`) which does not have a `setBorder` method.

The subsequent fix downcasts the container back to a `JPanel` which has and exposes the `setBorder` method as one of its public methods.

```
private Container currCntr = new JPanel(); //JPanel upcasted to type Container

//Container does not have a `setBorder` method
currCntr.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

//Downcasted to JPanel which has the setBorder method
((JPanel)currCntr).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun Same Question.  I earned many downvotes in my time, but I'm not sure about this one.

Comment: I hate downvotes without reason, +1 for correct and detailed answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast to `JPanel`

```
((JPanel)currCntr).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
currCntr.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));

//you can try createLineBorder, shuld be the same syntax.
```

It because you did not set attributes for the line border. Please try set attributes. such as thickness.

Comment: That does not relates to the question