# Can a cast operator be explicit?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-keyword, explicit

When it comes to constructors, adding the keyword `explicit` prevents an enthusiastic compiler from creating an object when it was not the programmer’s first intention. Is such mechanism available for casting operators too?

```
struct Foo
{
    operator std::string() const;
};
```

Here, for instance, I would like to be able to cast `Foo` into a `std::string`, but I don’t want such cast to happen implicitly.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Yes and No.

It depends on which version of C++, you're using.

- C++98 and C++03 do not support `explicit` type conversion operators
- But C++11 does.

Example,

```
struct A
{
    //implicit conversion to int
    operator int() { return 100; }

    //explicit conversion to std::string
    explicit operator std::string() { return "explicit"; } 
};

int main() 
{
   A a;
   int i = a;  //ok - implicit conversion 
   std::string s = a; //error - requires explicit conversion 
}
```

Compile it with `g++ -std=c++0x`, you will get this error:

> prog.cpp:13:20: error: conversion from 'A' to non-scalar type 'std::string' requested

Online demo : http://ideone.com/DJut1

But as soon as you write:

```
std::string s = static_cast<std::string>(a); //ok - explicit conversion
```

The error goes away : http://ideone.com/LhuFd

BTW, in C++11, the explicit conversion operator is referred to as *"contextual conversion operator"* if it converts to *boolean*. Also, if you want to know more about implicit and explicit conversions, read this topic:

- [Implicit VS Explicit Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099957/implicit-vs-explicit-conversion)

Comment: Even in C++03, it's easy to avoid the implicit conversion.  Just call the function `toString`, rather than `operator std::string`.  Of course, this may cause problems with some templates.  I've always used `toString`, and it's never caused me any problems, but I imagine that this could depend on your coding style.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Just like `operator std::string()`:-).

Comment: I use `to_string` instead. It helps that it's what C++11 calls it, so it helps write forwards-compatible code _and_ it helps with templates.

Comment: `std::string s(a)` or `std::string s{a}` should also work as `static_cast<std::string>(a)`.

Comment: In C++ 11, things like "if(std::cin)" is legal. Since the 'istream' class has a member "explicit operator bool() const;" why doesn't the compiler enforce the code to be "if(static_cast<bool>(std::cin))" ?

Comment: @Bin: Because the `explicit operator bool()`  is invoked *contextually* by the compiler when you write `if(std::cin)`. Note the conversion which occurs here is (informally) called *contextual* conversion, **not** *implicit* conversion.