# What do C/C++ expressions return?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop

What do the expressions in C++ return, the actual value obtained after applying the operators on the objects or true/false based on the calculated value ? Particularly :

In this code segment :

```
int i = 10, j = 5, k = 0;
i + j ;
k = i + j ;
while ( i + j )
{
    // Do something worth for the universe in this time
}
```

What will the expression written in line No. 2 return, `15` or `true` ? Will it return the same value in line No. 4 ? Is `15` always returned, but converted to `true` or `false` based on the context ?

I read this in [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) :

> A while has the form

```
while (condition)
     statement
```

> A while executes by (alternately) testing the condition and executing the associated statement until the condition
>   is false. A condition is an expression that yields a result that is
>   either true or false.

But expressions could be just plain objects as well right !? How are they supposed to mean a `true` or `false` ? For eg:

```
// Create an object `tempObject` of a class `SomeRandomClass`
while ( tempObject )
{

}
```

Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the "condition" in an `if` or `while` is not a direct boolean value (`true` or `false`) from the expression itself (`==` or `>` or `<=`, for example, would give a boolean value), the expression is seen as if it was a comparison as not equal to zero.

So:

```
int x = 25;

while(x)
 ...
```

is the same as

```
while (x != 0)
```

This applies to all types, such as pointers, integers and floating point values.

Edit as per comments below:

An object of a `class` or `struct` must be possible to convert into a `bool` in some way: Either the object has direct `operator bool()` like this:

```
class X
{
  private:
    int x;
  public:
    X(int xx = 0) x(xx) {}
    void setx(int xx) { x = xx; }
    bool operator bool() const { return x != 0; }
};
```

Now we can do:

```
X a(1);

if (a) ... 
a.setx(0);
if (a) ...
```

The first `if` will be true, the second `if` will be false.

If there isn't an `operator bool()` available, then the compiler may use `operator int()` or `operator void*` to convert the type, and then making the implicit `!= 0` comparison to produce a `bool` value.

Comment: Is an object treated in the same way ? eg. `while (object){}` ? Will that necessarily require `!=` (or `==`) operator to be defined for that object ?

Comment: If an object can't be turned into something that can be turned into a `bool`, then it will give an error. It requires an `operator int()` or `operator void*()` or similar to convert it to something that can be compared to 0.

Comment: Not entirely true that it's necessarily compared to 0. The expression in if/while statements will be tried to be converted to a boolean value. For integers, there is an implicit conversion, meaning 0 => false, everything else => true; but for objects, it's a different matter. There could e.g. be an explicit `operator bool()` as well

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, if there ISN'T an `operator bool()`, the compiler will pick something that can be converted to `bool` by using (an implicit) ` != 0`. If there is "nothing", then there will be an error "can't convert object to bool" or something like that.

Comment: I agree with @nyarlathotep. The whole "!=0" explanation is redundant. If the expression has type `bool`, it's used directly. If the expression can be converted to `bool`, then it's converted. Else, it's a type error.

Answer (score 2):

`0` (and `false`, in versions of C++ where that exists) means false; any other value means true.

Comment: Does `false` not exist in all versions of C++? I thought it was only C that introduced boolean literals later.

Comment: I know what you have said as a fact, but wanted to understand it. I wanted to understand how I should be approaching expressions and treat the output they produce. eg if condition would have been `while (std::cin >> value)`, what you are saying will hold true ?

Comment: @AmitTomar, That returns a `std::istream &` (`std::cin` in this case), which has `explicit operator bool()` (`operator void *()` in C++03) that converts its state to a boolean value.

Comment: @chris: I'm pretty sure that is was not there at the beginning.

Comment: @chris Can you please explain what you mean by `which has explicit operator bool() that converts its state to a boolean value` ?

Comment: @AmitTomar, You might want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239356/can-a-cast-operator-be-explicit). It allows your class to be explicitly converted to a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

To understand these code, please first go back to C:

Everthing which is 0 is false.
Everthing which is not 0 is true.

In your case the while loop then means
while ( 15 )
which is the same as
while ( true )

An endless loop...

Giving an object into such a code the object must behave at least as an integer or an boolean giving the while loop any evaluable expression, e.g.

```
public:
    operator bool() const
    {
         return myVar;
    }
```

where you store the while condition in myVar ...

Answer (score 1):

`i + j` has type `int` because both `i` and `j` are `int`s. The value of the expression is the sum of the two. In the statement

```
i + j;
```

the value is not used, so it is ignored. Chances are the compiler will omit the addition, since it has no side effects. In the statement

```
k = i + j;
```

the result is used; it is copied into `k`. In the statement

```
while (i + j) {
}
```

the value is used in a boolean context. Formally, it is "contextually converted to `bool`": zero is converted to `false` and any other value is converted to `true`.