# How to require an explicit cast

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, type-conversion

I have the following error:

```
error: use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous (with operand types 'InObj' and 'class PerformObj')
```

The reason why is because I provided a `vector<int>` conversion operator for `PerformObj` so that the results can be stored in a vector. However, the problem is, because `InObj` expects a `vector<int>` on the right hand side, it implicitly converts `PerformObj`, causing an issue. I would like to have it so that `PerformObj` can only be explicitly cast to a `vector<int>` (plus signs added for readability).

```
x is an integer
nums is a vector<int>
cube is a lambda
((x + in + nums) + perform + cube)
 ^inobj            ^ implicitly converted to vector<int>
^performobj
```

As you can see, `PerformObj` takes `InObj` as a left hand side parameter, but the addition of the conversion operator causes ambiguity.

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
std::vector<int> results = static_cast<vector<int>>(x in num perform cube);
```

For reference, here is the code:

```
InObj& operator+(InObj& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs) {
    lhs.rhs = rhs;
    return lhs;
} 

class PerformObj {
public:
    // snip
    operator std::vector<int>() const {
        std::vector<int> temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < lhs.rhs.size(); i++) {
            temp.push_back(rhs(lhs.rhs[i]));
        }
        return temp;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PerformObj& po);
} performobj;

PerformObj& operator+(const InObj& lhs, PerformObj& rhs) {
    rhs.lhs = lhs;
    return rhs;
}

// Error occurs on the following line
std::cout << x in nums perform cube << std::endl;
```

Comment: imo, i find cast operators to be evil, you get random side effects like inheriting operators from the class type of your cast operator.  why not provide a `std::vector<int> toVector() const` method?  That way no inherited operators for the `class PerformObj` from the `std::vector<int>` class.

Comment: A **cast** is always explicit: it's something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is right in the headline for the question:  Use the `explicit` keyword on the type conversion operator.

More here:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/explicit-ctors.html

But, you need C++11.  More here:  [Can a cast operator be explicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239356/can-a-cast-operator-be-explicit)

Comment: Wow, I feel really really dumb.

Comment: Don't feel dumb.  `explicit` on cast operators is a new C++11 feature.  Even I had to look it up to be sure.  C++ is a huge language, and C++11 is even more so.