# How to eliminate this extra element?

Tags: c++, file, io

I am writing a c++ function for reading the nth column of a tab delimited text file, here is what I have done:

```
typedef unsigned int  uint;


inline void fileExists (const std::string& name) {
    if ( access( name.c_str(), F_OK ) == -1 ) {
        throw std::string("File does not exist!");
    }
}

size_t bimNCols(std::string fn) {
    try {
        fileExists(fn);
        std::ifstream in_file(fn);
        std::string tmpline;
        std::getline(in_file, tmpline);
        std::vector<std::string> strs;
        strs = boost::split(strs, tmpline, boost::is_any_of("\t"), boost::token_compress_on);
        return strs.size();
    } catch (const std::string& e) {
        std::cerr << "\n" << e << "\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

typedef std::vector<std::string> vecStr;

vecStr bimReadCol(std::string fn, uint ncol_select) {
    try {
        size_t ncols = bimNCols(fn);
        if(ncol_select < 1 or ncol_select > ncols) {
            throw std::string("Your column selection is out of range!");
        }

        std::ifstream in_file(fn);
        std::string tmpword;
        vecStr colsel; // holds the column of strings
        while (in_file) {
            for(int i=1; i<ncol_select; i++) {
                in_file >> tmpword;
            }
            in_file >> tmpword;
            colsel.push_back(tmpword);
            in_file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        return colsel;

    } catch (const std::string& e) {
        std::cerr << "\n" << e << "\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

The problem is, in the `bimReadCol` function, at the last line, after

```
in_file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

`in_file.good()` still evaluates to `true`. So, suppose I have a text file `test.txt` like this:

```
a 1 b 2
a 1 b 2
a 1 b 2
```

`bimReadCol("test.txt", 3)` would return a vector `(b, b, b, b)`, with an extra element.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Note: Pleas use return values and less exceptions - and if you use an exception, derive from std::exception

Comment: @DieterLücking could you please give a reference on return values vs exceptions? I have no idea how to use return value for the same purpose as exceptions.

Comment: No, but in my opinion `fileExists` should certainly not throw an exception.

Comment: oh, that one. but why not?

Comment: @DieterLücking I just found creating an exception class with customized error message is too much of a hassle, so I figured, why not just throw a an error message directly? Could you please explain why this is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution for line oriented input is to read line by
line, then parse each line:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( in_file, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream parser( line );
    for ( int i = 1; parser >> tmpword && i <= ncol_select; ++ i ) {
    }
    if ( parser ) {
        colsel.push_back( tmpword );
    }
    //  No need for any ignore.
}
```

The important thing is that you must absolutely test *after* the
input (be it from `in_file` or `parser`) before you use the
value.  A test before the value was read doesn't mean anything
(as you've seen).

Comment: what is `if(parser)` testing?

Comment: It's a cast of `std::istringstream` to bool it's [`here`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: @luk32 that is no cast, but a conversion

Comment: Fair enough. But ain't it called type cast operator? E.g: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239356/can-a-cast-operator-be-explicit), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y.aspx). The difference lies only in being explicit or implicit?

Comment: @luk32 Within the standard, at least, a cast is one of several different operators, which cause a conversion.  A conversion may occur as the result of a cast (explicit conversion) or otherwise (implicit conversion).

Comment: @qed `parser` is a stream.  Streams convert implicitly to `bool` (earlier to `void const*`, which could be used as a `bool`), evaluating to `true` if there has been no error, and `false` otherwise.  And while I normally try to avoid implicit conversions, this one is so ubiquito9us that anything else would seem strange.  (This is exactly the same conversion which occurs in the `while` condition: `std::getline` returns a reference to the istream, which is implicitly converted to `bool`.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. The last line of the text file does not contain a newline, that's why `in_file` evaluates
to `true` at the last line.

I think I should calculate the number of lines of the file, then replace `while(in_file)` with a
for loop.

If someone has a better idea, please post it and I will accept.

#### Update

The fix turns out to be rather simple, just check if `tmpword` is empty:

```
vecStr bimReadCol(std::string fn, uint ncol_select) {
    try {
        size_t ncols = bimNCols(fn);
        if(ncol_select < 1 or ncol_select > ncols) {
            throw std::string("Your column selection is out of range!");
        }

        std::ifstream in_file(fn);
        vecStr colsel; // holds the column of strings
        std::string tmpword;
        while (in_file) {
            tmpword = "";
            for(int i=1; i<=ncol_select; i++) {
                in_file >> tmpword;
            }
            if(tmpword != "") {
                colsel.push_back(tmpword);
            }
            in_file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        return colsel;

    } catch (const std::string& e) {
        std::cerr << "\n" << e << "\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

As @James Kanze has pointed out, even if the last line contains a newline, `in_file`
would still evaluate to `true`, but since we are at the end of file, the next reading into
`tmpword` will be empty, so we will be fine as long as we check that.

Comment: More likely, the last line of the text file does contain a new line.  The problem you're encountering is that ignoring up to the next `'\n'` doesn't set any error status, even if you reach the end of file.  The error is only set once you try to read something beyond the end of file.