# How to implement C++ stream manipulator endl correctly?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, manipulators

I'm trying to implement a manipulator for my `stream` class. I don't know much about manipulators, but I think I'm doing everything right. The relevant parts of the code are below:

```
class stream
{
public:
    stream& operator<<(bool b) { // send bool value and return *this; }
    stream& operator<<(const char str[]) { // send string and return *this }
}; 

inline stream& endl(stream& s) 
{
    return s << "\r\n";
}


class stream stream;

int main()
{
    stream << endl;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but instead of calling `endl` the compiler is calling `stream::operator<<(bool)`. Any idea?

Comment: Your `endl` is a function and not an object.

Comment: Yes, it is. What's wrong?

Comment: So `endl` is actually a *pointer to a function* (e.g. some number like 0x3758fd..) and thus it is only possible to convert a number to `bool` in your case so it pick that overload. (look at @nwp's answer for clarification)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing `stream << endl;` the compiler has to pick an overload from the `operator <<`s you provided. `endl` is not convertible to `const char *`, but it is convertible to `bool`, so that's what you get.

You probably meant to add an overload

```
stream& operator<<(stream &(*function)(stream &)) {
   return function(*this);
}
```

inside of `class stream` that handles function pointers correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `endl` is neither a `bool` nor a `const char[]` (it is a free function), it is implicitly converted to a `bool`(`true`) and the following function is called:

```
stream::stream& operator<<(bool b)
```

You could define `endl` to be of a special type `endl_t` and define the right operator for it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

//Just make the operators `explicit`. See [this excellent answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8239402/5470596).

class stream
{
public:
    stream& operator<<(bool b) { std::cout << "bool\n" ; return *this; }
    stream& operator<<(const char str[]) { std::cout << "const char[]\n" ; return *this; }
};

struct endl_t {} endl;

stream& operator<<(stream& s, endl_t)
{
    s << "\r\n";
    return s;
}


int main()
{
    stream s;
    s << endl; // prints "const char[]"
}
```

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/435ce2a259c12040)