# Explicit up casting & Implicit up casting

Tags: java, polymorphism, implicit, explicit, upcasting

I'm trying to find the difference between Explicit up casting and Implicit up casting but there's not so much posts about them. Somebody help me pls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit VS Explicit Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099957/implicit-vs-explicit-conversion)

Comment: That's a C++ answer so probably not that helpful.