# Why is const char INITIAL='G' not an assignment statement?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, variable-assignment

I am having problems in understanding this statement. I don't know why this is not usual like others.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470553/initialization-parenthesis-vs-equals-sign

Comment: With the edit, the question no longer makes sense. "in understanding this statement." Which statement? You haven't included it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: why it's tagged both C and C++?

Comment: @Borgleader Ive mentioned the statement in the question. My edit removed a sentence which I thought might drive the topic some other way.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc what else should i tag in to?

Comment: @KuharanBhowmik Its in the title, not the actual question.

Comment: @Borgleader i thought the bold letters would make some sense to you.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages and should not be tagged at the same time except in special cases

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc i tagged to bring more people in to help in my doubt thats it. And yes i got my answer. By the way why am I getting downvoted for this question?

Comment: @KuharanBhowmik Tags are not for _bringing more people into help_, but to narrow the relation of your question. C and C++ are different languages as mentioned, and there are rare cases where answers will be the same for both of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initialization: parenthesis vs. equals sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470553/initialization-parenthesis-vs-equals-sign)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc so what do you think the proper tag should be. Ps I am new here

Comment: The proper tag should be whichever language you're asking about. Being new here doesn't make a difference

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc i did the right thing then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment means giving a new value to an already existing object. Even though `const char INITIAL='G';` has an = sign, it is **not** an assignment, because it is **creating** a new object, not modifying an existing one. `char INITIAL; INITIAL='G';` would be an assignment, because `INITIAL` already exists when the new value is, well, assigned.

Comment: thanks for this :)

Comment: const char INITIAL='G' 
Here this statement actually creates INITIAL variable and then puts G into it. So in a way that variable is already existing. Just a thought.