# c++ Type declaration before function invocation?

Tags: c++, types, syntax

I'm looking through the source code for the v8 javascript engine ([here's the github link](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/parsing/parsing.cc#L33)), and on line 33 of parsing.cc, there's this statement within a function:

```
Parser parser(info);
```

I'm only used to seeing a type declaration like this before an assignment, such as:

```
Parser myparser = Parser(...);
```

So what does the first example do?  Why not just invoke `parser(info)` without a type declaration?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doesn't that just invoke the `Parser` constructor? My C++ is rusty, but this just looks like a variable initialization.

Comment: This is no different from `int n(5);`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470553/initialization-parenthesis-vs-equals-sign

Comment: I'd argue that it's not a duplicate.  My question calls for people to help identify a syntactic form, whereas the referenced question asks for comparison between two forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
Parser parser(info);
```

constructs a `Parser` object by calling the constructor that takes `info` as the argument.

This method of constructing an object is called [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

You may also use the form

```
Parser parser = Parser(info);
```

to construct the object. This method of constructing an object is called [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing an object of type Parser on the stack. (or as the comments say depending on the block scope this could be a global variable, not able to discern from the info available but more than likely it is the stack :) 
[Object creation on the stack/heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157122/object-creation-on-the-stack-heap)

Comment: How do you know it is on the stack?

Comment: @juanchopanza If it isn't using "new" and going to the heap, then it would be the stack.

Comment: No, it could also be static storage.

Comment: Wouldn't that need the static qualifier for that?

Comment: Nope. Who said anything about block scope?

Comment: Good points, I was assuming... Could be global, so if it is global, then it would be stored elsewhere. I will edit that. But if it was a static and out of the block scope of a function, then it would still need the qualifier static on it.