# Difference between = and {} syntaxes for initializing a variable in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, value-initialization, copy-initialization

I have read quite a few C++ codes, and I have come across two methods of initialising a variable.

Method 1:

```
int score = 0;
```

Method 2:

```
int score {};
```

I know that `int score {};` will initialise the score to 0, and so will `int score = 0;`

What is the difference between these two? I have read [initialization: parenthesis vs. equals sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470553/initialization-parenthesis-vs-equals-sign) but that does not answer my question. I wish to know what is the  difference between **equal sign** and **curly brackets**, not parenthesis. Which one should be used in which case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int score = 0;` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), as the effect, `score` is initialized to the specified value `0`.

> Otherwise (if neither `T` nor the type of `other` are class types), [standard conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) are used, if necessary, to convert the value of `other` to the cv-unqualified version of `T`.

`int score {};` performs [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) with braced initializer, which was supported since C++11, as the effect,

> otherwise, the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

`score` is of built-in type `int`, it's [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) at last, i.e. initialized to `0`.

> If `T` is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero [explicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) to `T`.

Comment: Is there an advantage in using one over the other?

Comment: An entire story should be written about brace initializers.

Comment: The advantage is that you avoid copy-construction

Comment: @AdityaPrakash Since they have the same effect, I think it's just a coding style issue. For the 1st one, it could be used to initialize to the specified value; for the 2nd one, it could be used to initialize to the *default value*.

Comment: That depends on what you are initializing. In the example as written there is no difference.

Comment: Empty braces is *value-initialization*,  which for the case of a variable of type `int`, resolves to zero-initialization

Answer (score 0):

You may have some interest in ISO/IEC 14882 8.5.1. It will tell you that a *brace-or-equal-initializer* can be *assignment-expression* or *braced-init-list*. 
In Method2, you are using an default initializer on a scalar type, witch should be set to zero.