# Initializing variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

I saw someone say in a comment that initializing variables with ' {} ' is better than with  ' = ' .
Is this true ? if it is explain why please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will find help here, but only for questions that are answerable according to SO rules. SO is not a forum, but is a Q&A site. That means that we expect precise questions for which a precise answer is possible. As a new user, you really should read [ask]. I am sorry, but without more context (references of the comment, or examples) this question will be hard to answer.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405190/difference-between-and-syntaxes-for-initializing-a-variable-in-c

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes that's what i'm looking for thank you. should i leave this post or delete it ?

Comment: @KenZa: It is up to you. I have just marked it as a duplicate to prevent others to try to answer.